# How to Handle Accept Terms and Condition Accept button in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

How to handle the Accept All button that appears with the page loading.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: That would be great you either share the URL or DOM structure.

Answer (score 1):

To click on <kbd>Accept All</kbd> button  you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using [java](/questions/tagged/java) and `XPATH`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='optanon-allow-all accept-cookies-button']"))).click();
  ```
- Using [python](/questions/tagged/python) and `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.optanon-allow-all.accept-cookies-button"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : For *python* clients you have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply click "Accept All" button after page is loading.

Comment: But it's showing me the exception: Element <button class="optanon-allow-all accept-cookies-button"> could not be scrolled into view

Comment: can you share inspect of that element?( "Accept All")

Comment: use this xpath to click "accept all" button   
//button[@title='Accept All']